# Norm of $l_p^w$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

X is a Banach space and $l_p^w(X)=\{x:\mathbb{N}\to X : \forall x'\in X', \sum_k |x'(x(k))|^p<\infty\}$. The norm is $wp(x):=\underbrace{sup}_{||x'||=1} (\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x'(x(k))|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ My problem is to show why $wp(x+y) \leq wp(x)+wp(y)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please, consider to take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y\in \ell^{w}_{p}(X)$ and $x'\in X'$ with $\|x'\|= 1$. Since $x'$ is linear we have:

$$(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x'(x(k)+y(k))|^p)^{1/p}=(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x'(x(k))+x'(y(k))|^p)^{1/p}.$$
By the triangular inequality in $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ we obtain:
$$(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x'(x(k))+x'(y(k))|^p)^{1/p}\leq(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x'(x(k))|^p)^{1/p}+(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x'(y(k))|^p)^{1/p}\leq wp(x)+wp(y).$$

Finally taking the supremum on the left hand side we obtain $wp(x+y)\leq wp(x)+wp(y)$

Comment: Can you just put the supremum on an inequality and it's still right?

Comment: Could you be more precise? because I do not understand what your comment mean.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand your proof, thanks!